# Squirrel client not opening

Tags: vertica, squirrel-sql

I have been using Squirrel SQL client to access Vertica (on a Windows 7 machine). It was working fine until last week but I am unable to open the Squirrel anymore and it throws an error

```
    "error occurred initializing plugin: oracle".
```

I haven't installed any additional plugins and this has been working fine until last week. Can someone let me know how to debug this error?

Comment: Was just a Java installation issue...apparently didn't work with Java 7...installing Java 6 solved the issue for me

Comment: mark Question s solved !

Comment: Hi Up_One could you please tell me how I can do that? I am unable to find options for that

Comment: it's an option ! to answer your own question - at the bottom of the page !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just a Java installation issue...apparently didn't work with Java 7...installing Java 6 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Delete codecompletionprefs.xml file, hope it will be better. My problem has been solved.
C:\Users[Your user name].squirrel-sql\plugins\codecompletion